# Getting nil values using NSDate (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, option-type

I'm new to iOS dev and getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The value at the bottom of xCode for self (NSDate) is correct but dateStringFormatter and d are showing the memory address instead of a value, and dateString remains unchanged. Any ideas? I had this code working earlier and have been trying to fix it after a bad commit, so I'm thinking maybe something to do with storyboard / something that wouldn't show up in code? 
Here's the code:

```
extension NSDate{
convenience
init(dateString:String) {
    let dateStringFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    dateStringFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:
    "en_US_POSIX")
    let d = dateStringFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    self.init(timeInterval:0, sinceDate:d)
    }
}

class EditViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
 ........
@IBAction func btnSetDate(sender: UIButton) {
    let newDate = NSDate(dateString: "10-33")
    StartDatePicker.date = newDate
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either changed the date string literal or the format. Make one of the following changes:

```
let newDate = NSDate(dateString: "10:33")
// or
dateStringFormatter.dateFormat = "hh-mm"
```